Convert Nvarchar to datetime data type
I have a legacy database. This database has stored the data in the format '02/10/2015 14:26:48'.
I am trying to convert this date&time to apply sorting to fulfill my requirements:
DECLARE @date nvarchar(50) = N'02/10/2015 14:26:48'

SELECT CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(@date, 19), 126)

But I am getting the following error:

SQL Error [241] [S0001]: An error occurred during the current command (Done status 0). Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.


A very quick look at the documentation tells me your data is not in the style 126 (yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm), so why it fails is quite obvious. Use an approriate style and the error disappears.

Try CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(@date, 19), 101)

I think you would do better to use TRY_CONVERT, in this case TRY_CONVERT (DATETIME, '02/10/2015 14:26:48'). If you write something like ...WHERE TRY_CONVERT (DATETIME, your_date) IS NOT NULL, you can exclude incorrect data. Note this assumes your date is the 10th February, not the 2nd October. You need to extend it otherwise.

The style you have used (126) is for the ISO8601 format yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm. You need to chose a style that represents your date format. I can't tell from your question what this is though, is your example date 10th February or 2nd October?

@JonasMetzler Metzler - I tried. Try_convert  - returns NULL.

@OP, do just randomly take style number and try to apply CONVERT with? Or where did you find 126? I'm curious because this comes up all the time

"I tried. Try_convert - returns NULL" And did you correct the style code, @SabyasachiMukherjee ?

No, it returns a datetime, see https://dbfiddle.uk/LMqxiErb

02/10/2015 14:26:48 btw says nothing, is it DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY

No, @siggemannen , it's clearly the 2015th day of the 10th month of the 2nd year. ;)

@JonasMetzler - the syntax I was trying for try_convert was incorrect. Thanks your answer solves it

@siggemannen - to answer your query - I got this from here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

If your format is dd/MM/yyyy you should use the style 103, if it is MM/dd/yyyy then use 101, but I would not advise doing this without a style because with different session/server settings you will get different results. You may think this will never happen, but why risk it for the sake of a few extra characters. With TRY_CONVERT this is even worse because you won't get an error, you'll just get missing/incorrect data

@SabyasachiMukherjee  that document clearly states that style 126 represents yyyy-MM-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm. The example you presumably copied also clearly denotes it's using ISO formatting "the date and time in the ISO 8601 format." and the literal string is claerly in that format ('2006-04-25T15:50:59.997'). You can't just copy pasta code and expect it to work; read the documentation and take the time to understand it and the code you copy.

@GarethD I'm used to initally set the settings as I want them, so I wouldn't need it in every query. But your point is clearly important. If they don't use an initial setup, this is absolutely required and far cleaner.

One way would be to pull out the invividual parts of the date part and reorder them to utc? Swap day and month around to required format
DECLARE @date nvarchar(50) = N'02/10/2015 14:26:48'

SELECT CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(@date, 7, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@date, 4, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@date, 1, 2) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(@date, 12, 8))


Why should they do that? What's the advantage over simple functions like TRY_CONVERT?

Not in this particular case, but this technique can cover cases where CONVERT don't support the particular format the text column is in.

Could you please improve your answer by explaining a clear use case of your idea where others don't work?

Interestingly, in part dur to SQL Server's YYYY-DD-MM interpretation quirk, the above yields the wrong results for both DD/MM/YYYY and MM/DD/YYYY source data formats (assuming a matching SET DATEFORMAT option is set). Fiddle.
